# Start container with multiple network interfaces

Tags: docker, docker-network

With 1.9, is there a way to start a container directly with two or more network interfaces?

You can do it after the container is started with "docker network connect", but it means the process is already running and might miss the creation of the new one.

Comment: `docker service create --network frontend --network backend ...`

Comment: I had an issue when mixing ipvlan driver and bridge driver (both wanted to create teh route for 0.0.0.0/0), setting the brdige driver network ("default") to also use the use the ipvlan driver would create containers ok. i found this post helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71273149/how-to-connect-additional-network-to-container-with-ipvlan-l3-network

Answer (score 81):

### With Docker 1.12+ it's possible to add more than one network interface to a docker container with about five lines of shell commands.

##### First: you must create the Docker networks `network1` and `network2` via `docker network create` shell command:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge network1 --subnet=172.19.0.0/24
docker network create --driver=bridge network2 --subnet=172.19.1.0/24
```

notes:

- in this example there are two networks
- for N networks, you would have N lines ensuring each network name and subnet is unique

##### Second: create the container and attach the Docker networks (prior to starting the container) via shell commands:

```
docker create --network=network1 --name container_name image_name:tag_name
docker network connect network2 container_name
```

notes:

- the `docker create` has the first network on purpose because otherwise a default network interface will be created and your container will have 3 network interfaces instead of the expected 2 network interfaces

##### Third: start your container

```
docker start container_name
```

tested with:

- docker version 20.x, rockylinux:8
- when i get into the container command line shell `ifconfig` shows two network interfaces `eth0`, `eth1` (not counting `lo`)

---

p.s. Also, you can start the container attaching the dockerhost network interfaces by using the --network=host argument in docker run:

```
docker run --net=host image_name:tag_name
```

p.p.s. If you want the container to be interactive change the `create` command and `start` command to:

```
docker create -it --name container_name image_name:tag_name bash --login
docker start -ai container_name
```

Comment: if container is started, it still connect to a new network and keep origin network accessable. docker version: 1.13.1

Comment: This does not create multiple network interfaces, it simply adds multiple IP addresses to eth0.

Comment: Some may have pointed out that this is not posible but now it it is posible [see more](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/17750) . Even if you container is running already you can attach another network interface to it, you  just neet to run the following command: `docker network connect <network id or name> <container-id or name>`

Answer (score 8):

Does someone still look for the answer of this issue?
There are 2 solutions to do this:
First is the one almost detailed completely here, but it do works with current docker releases - complete tutorial can be found here [docker hub forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/adding-a-new-nic-to-a-docker-container-in-a-specific-order/19173)

Solution 2 is to do everything in the rock-bottom layer. I have included the details comment section of the link above, which I also copy here:
Since docker is also using linux’s networking namespaces you can do this in the rock-bottom layer as well. Unfortunately, Docker tries to hide this from the user, but the namespaces are still existing under the hood. In order to get them to be managed by ip netns tool, do the following:

1. get the process id (pid) of your running container:

`$ sudo docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' <container name>`

`<container name>` is not your `label:tag` name, it is the name that docker automatically assign to it once a container is fired up - get yours via `docker ps` command and look for the last column (NAME).

2. create a symlink from the /proc/ filesystem to /var/run/

2.1. First, create a netns directory in /var/run/

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /var/run/netns
```

2.2. Using the PID you have just obtained, create the symlink

```
$ sudo ln -sf /proc/<PID>/ns/net /var/run/netns/<YOUR DESIRED NETNS NAME FOR YOU CONTAINER>
```

Now, if you execute `ip netns list`, you will see the networking namespace of your container.

From now on, there are no docker specific stuff, just create a veth pair, bring them up, and attach one end of it to the container and you are fine:

```
$ sudo ip link add veth1_container type veth peer name veth1_root
$ sudo ifconfig veth1_container up
$ sudo ifconfig veth1_root up
$ sudo ip link set veth1_container netns <YOUR NETNS NAME>
$ sudo ip netns exec <YOUR NETNS NAME> ifconfig veth1_container up
```

The last command might be a bit overcomplicated, but it seemed that bringing up this interface natively in the container is not possible due to missing permissions  :)

Note that the MAC address could also be changed in the same way I have shown in solution 1, before attaching it to the container or after - does not really matter, just different commands need to be used (recall the permission issue just mentioned above).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Go to here for a script doing everything for you with this regard: [https://github.com/cslev/add_veth_to_docker/](https://github.com/cslev/add_veth_to_docker/)

Comment: Important advantage of the manual approach is that it can add interface of any supported type, not just veth (a.t.m. I am interested in vcan).

Comment: I am leaving a downvote, because your answer is just ... too over engineered and complicated in general. Not just the last command. It's too overengineered when it doesn't have to and it isn't compliant with good docker practices. The main reason we use docker is just to get rid of this. I dont see how this would help someone rather than making him even more confused, especially when this isn't what the Question asks. The question asks how to start a docker container with multiple networks without having to add them later. And you completely missed the point with your hacks here.

Comment: @Eksapsy Why would you down-vote the only guy who actually answered the question? The question wasn't framed in the context of simplicity or best-practices; but the question was answered.

Comment: What do you mean? :/ A bad answer is still an answer, we have downvotes and upvotes for a reason. What else would I use them for? If the answer was against the rules I would just report it, not downvote it.

Comment: Take my upvote. I've been searching for this for ages.

Answer (score 6):

As @gesellix answered, currently its not possible.

You can find this issue under 
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17750

There are some pending improvements in this area.
As I see from discussions - current idea is to create container (with docker create), attach networks (docker network connect) and then start (docker start).

You can check reasoning in comments of https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/17796

**UPD:** #17750 is closed and will be available in 1.10

Comment: And what if I need to have multiple ip addresses on the same network? Network connect just changes ip to another.

Answer (score 5):

This should answer your questions:
https://success.docker.com/article/multiple-docker-networks

Example given in article above:

```
    STEP 1:
    ## Create Networks ##
    docker network create bluenet
    docker network create rednet`

    STEP 2a: (automatically running)
    ## Create (1) Container in background called "c1" running busybox image ##
    docker run -itd --net bluenet --name c1 busybox sh

    STEP 2b: (created only to run later)
    ## Create (1) Container (notice no run flag - it is only created) ##
    docker create -it --net bluenet --name c1 busybox sh

    STEP 3:
    ## Attach remaining Network ##
    docker network connect rednet c1
    docker start c1
```

Docker does a great job of documenting features as they roll out.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible. The docs also show that the necessary command line option `--net` only accepts a single network name: http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings

Please also keep in mind that Docker 1.9 constantly updates the `/etc/hosts` file inside your containers, so that a running process cannot rely on the initial state of that file. The best way would be to make your process aware of updates, either through manually reading the `/etc/hosts` file or by querying a dns server. That way you wouldn't have issues when the second network will be connected.

Comment: I can affirm. I tried `docker run -it  --network bridge --network mynet /bin/bash` -- no luck, `invalid reference format`. Also tried two args to the option `... --network bridge mynet...` but Docker thinks `mynet` is the image I want to use.