# Windows: How to created a new Ethernet network from command line

Tags: windows, docker, containers

I have an windows container which created by windows docker. Now I want to add two or more Ethernet Adapter from command line. Because windows container cannot start GUI, so I have to do this from command line. How can I do?

Comment: Are you trying to add the ethernet adapter inside the container?

Comment: Yes, I want to add the ethernet adapter inside the container. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

To create a new virtual network see `[docker network create][1]`

However in the body of your post you mention wanting to create new Ethernet Adapters. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110416/start-container-with-multiple-network-interfaces)

Comment: Thanks for your mention, I changed the question.

Comment: I want add a new Ethernet Adapters in docker container, not on the physical host.

Comment: @kongxx see the link in my answer above.