# How to connect additional network to container with ipvlan l3 network?

Tags: docker, networking

My setup: I have an external defined ipvlan l3 network connect to the host nic named dmz_net. It span an isolated subnet to connect several containers. This works as expected.
Now I want to create a service stack with docker compose. It has a backend container (database) and a service container. The backend container has his own internal defined network (default bridge mode). The service container should connected to the 'dmz_net' network and to the backend network.

docker compose extract

```
networks:
  dmz:
    external:
      name: dmz_net
  backend:
    internal: true

services:
  service:
    networks:
      dmz:
        ipv4_address: ${IPV4}
      backend:
```

`docker network inspect dmz_net`:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "dmz_net",
        "Id": "9b98f5e01245c8081a10fe377a450e1e5eedd08511b4e715b4469986d7aadce6",
        "Created": "2022-02-21T20:37:58.688032649+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "ipvlan",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.20.10.0/24"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
        },
        "Options": {
            "ipvlan_mode": "l3",
            "parent": "enp36s0f1.20"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Starting the service container failed with the error message `failed to set gateway while updating gateway: file exists`.

How can I get it to work? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3):

After a long night of experiments and to little sleep, I found the solution...

Unfortunately it isn't mentioned in the docker documentation, only an 7 years old issue describe the problem and a [PR](https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/pull/778) to fix it. A look into the code give me the light...

*The solution*: using ipvlan L3 driver (instead of the default bridge) for the internal (backend) network and setting 'internal=true' do the trick.
This definition prevent the network connection later on to create a default gateway, which is not possible in case another (external reachable, means internal=false) L3 network is connected.

Hopefully others find the information helpful.

docker-compose.yml snippet:

```
networks:
  backend:
    internal: true
    driver: ipvlan
    driver_opts:
      ipvlan_mode: l3
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have been trying to set this up since yesterday, without success. Can you share  a sample docker-compose, if possible?

Comment: Add a snippet in my original answer